# Android : Custom titleBar for complete Application in android?

Tags: android, titlebar

In my application i have a tabView , with 5 tab buttons. I need a custom title bar for all the views in myapplication .Is it possible to have common titlebar for all of my views

Answer (score 0):

Can be done, but you need to write at least some 2 lines of code in each view.

In your Activities layout XML, you could use

```
<include android:id="@+id/header_include" layout="@layout/common_header" />
```

And in your Activities onCreate, you would call a helper method to setup the header:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Helper.setupHeader(this, "Title", 5);
}
```

The 3rd param could be the index of the tabview item to highlight initially.